# Getting Default value in React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks

I have an input field with a default value

```
 <input type="text" name="default"  value="one" />
```

I'm using react hook to use state

```
const [def, setdef] = useState({Default:""})
```

what I want is to set the input default value *one* to the state

**Desired Output**

```
setdef({...def, Default:"one"})
```

how can I achieve this? I know about the onChange function but I don't think it will work.

any better suggestion is appreciated. thanks in advance

Comment: Initialize the state's Default key with a value of "one" then? `const [def, setdef] = useState({Default:"one"})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you need to create a hook with a default string, like this:

```js
const Component = () => {
  const [string, setString] = useState("hello") // <-- this is the default value of the input
  
  // Set the hook value into the content of the input
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setString(event.target.value);
  }

  return <input value={string} onChange={handleChange} />
}
```

The input's content would be "hello" by default, but the user can change it. Delete the `onChange` event to make it read-only.

Answer (score -1):

(mi comentario estaba en español, perdón por la mala traducción no soy bueno en el ingles)

I think this is what you need

When using hooks one can specify what value it will have by default like this:

```
const [def, setdef] = useState("one")
```

by doing what is above you will get the value that I add in quotes when occupying -> def.

```
<input type="text" name="default" value={def} />
```

the input will obtain an initial value that will be "one"

and if you want to modify its value you will only have to do this:

```
setdef("new value")
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site that operates in English only. Please translate your answer into English.